# Rendering problems when scrolling in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, scroll, rendering, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I'm having problems in several versions of Chrome when trying to scroll through a short (25 item) list in my app.  The screen smears like so:

[image: scroll render problem in angularjs]

I've stripped the controller and `ng-repeat` element so that there are no watchers whatsoever.  It's simply adding binding for basic attributes.

I'm also using angular ui-router, and this is inside of a `ui-view`.

Problem is somewhat consistent in Chrome and shows up in Safari as well.  No problems in Firefox (that I can tell).  Have not tested in IE.

Any idea what is causing this behavior?

**EDIT**

Also potentially noteworthy: this goes away on my laptop (MBP) if I plug in an external mouse.  Not sure why.  It is a problem on other machines too though, so not specific to my setup.

Comment: Can you reproduce if there is no angular in the picture at all? Just HTML and CSS?

Comment: can u provide demo/jsfiddle for this?

Comment: If you can provide a demo for that, im sure we can test it for you and show if this is just your laptop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm able to reproduce the behavior consistently by setting `height: 100%` on any element being used for `ui-view`.  I had originally done this to allow for pushed (but not sticky) footers, but will need to find a workaround.

Removing `height: 100%` from the `ui-view` elements solved this for me.